# Split RDD with Apache Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have the following RDD:

```
x: Array[String] =
Array("Et: NT=grouptoClassify,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=app_1,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=app_exmpl_2,DB-exec,MDBConnection,NR
group: NT=apprexec,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,Ready
group: NT=nt_prblm_app,hadoop-exec,sparkConnection,NR
```

I just want to get the first part of every part of this RDD as you can see in the next example:

```
Et: NT=grouptoClassify
group: NT=app_1
group: NT=app_exmpl_2
group: NT=apprexec
group: NT=nt_prblm_app
```

This is what I am trying.

```
//Here I get the RDD:
var x = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(value)).collect()
//Try to split it
x = x.map(g => g.split(",")(0))
```

This is what I am trying but is not working for me because I just get the first item:

```
Et: NT=grouptoClassify
```

I am new with Apache Spark Scala. If you need something more just tell me it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `var` with Spark rdds and dataframes. Use immutable `val` objects:

```scala
  val rdd = 
    sparkSession
      .sparkContext
      .parallelize(List(value))
      .map(g => g.split(",").head)
  
  val strings = rdd.collect()
```

- `collect` is called in the end. This retrieves the distributed data on the driver i.e. those strings

Here is the [RDD programming guide](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html).

Comment: Hi gatear, thank you for your help but in this way I get the same that I am getting in the example, just the first part: Et: NT=grouptoClassify

Comment: Aa my bad. So this is a question regarding what regex to use

Comment: so to do this, the way is use a Regex?

Comment: Yep. Here are some [examples in Scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.5/scala/util/matching/Regex.html)